In Ubuntu 24, how to configure Alt + Tab to switch between different apps and skip other windows of the same app
This is almost a duplicate of this question except for Ubuntu 24 (I tried the selected answer, CompizConfig seems to not have a Unity plugin anymore)

The shortcut was changed. You can use Super + Tab to achieve the same behaviour.
(Super key is the Windows key on most classic keyboards.) As you already noticed, Alt + Tab now emulates the way the shortcut behaves in Windows.
I know this doesn't exactly answer the question, but maybe you're not aware of this and it could solve your problem at least partially.
